# How to get the position of a row after sorting the table?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table like this

```
ID            TOTALMARKS
___           __________  
12            623
32            350
14            944
11            540
17            549
```

I  want to sort the data of the table in the descending order of the TOTALMARKS and then after sorting it I want to get the position of the specific ID.

In this case, 944 is the highest TOTALMARKS of ID 14, hence its position will be 1st (which will be on the top after sorting). Hence, what I want is, just the position of the corresponding ID after the TOTALMARKS is sorted.

Here, when I want to know the position of ID 17 then I will expect the result as 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a subquery:

```
select 1 + count(*)
from t
where t.marks > (select t2.marks from t where t2.id = 14);
```

Note:  This implements the functionality of `rank()`, so ids with the same value of `marks` get the same rank.  And, there are holes (So, scores of 100,100,99 give 1, 1, 2).  If you don't want holes, then use `count(distinct marks)` instead of `count(*)`.